# Creating a function programmatically

Tags: python, function, combinations, programmatically-created

There are lots of interesting posts on this subject, but I seem to either not understand their answers, or aiming for something different. Here is what I am trying to do. I have two (or more) functions that I want to combine into a new function. The following snippet shows what I start with, and what I would like to end up with.

```py
def a(x):
    0.2 * x[1] - 0.4 * x[0]

def b(x):
    0.4 * x[0] - 0.2 * x[1]

def ab(x):
    return [0.2 * x[1] - 0.4 * x[0], 0.4 * x[0] - 0.2 * x[1]]
```

the catch being, that I would like to create `ab` at run time dynamically.
I have a list `ml` with all functions so I could do the following inside a new function

```py
def abl(x):
    ml = [a, b]
    rl = []
    i = 0
    for f in ml:
        rl.append(f(x[i]))
        i = i + 1
```

and then call `abl`. This code combines the individual functions and results in the expected output.  However, for each call to `abl`  `rl` has to be built anew, which seems wasteful.

Is there another way of combining `a` and `b` in order to create a new function `ab`?

Comment: I didn't get it. What's the problem of `ab(x)` ?

Comment: The code you have posted for `abl` doesn't seems complete. Please provide a complete, reproducible example.

Comment: have you tried `eval` https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval

Comment: You don't need an `i`. More pythonic to do `for f, xi in zip(ml, x)` and use `xi` instead of `x[i]`. Actually you don't need this at all, since you want to pass the entire `x` to both `a()` and `b()` functions. Just do `for f in ml: rl.append(f(x))`

Comment: Also, you'd create a new `rl` every time you call `ab()` anyway - creating it the way you do in `abl()` is no different from creating it the way you do in `ab()`

Comment: The rather more interesting question is whether Python can automatically *inline* `a` and `b` in a function like `ab = lambda x: [a(x), b(x)]`. (The answer is no, unfortunately.)

Comment: nothing wrong with ab, but a bit tedious with hundreds of functions.

Comment: why not `def abl(x): return [a(x), b(x)]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can dynamically return new functions via [lambda expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions):

```
def a(x):
    return 0.2 * x[1] - 0.4 * x[0]

def b(x):
    return 0.4 * x[0] - 0.2 * x[1]

def combine(func1, func2):
    return lambda x: [func1(x), func2(x)]
    
ab = combine(a, b)
print(ab([1.3, 2.9]))
```

Output:

```
[0.05999999999999994, -0.05999999999999994]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can extend [@Random Davis's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70218325/843953) `lambda` approach to any number of functions using [`*args`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/args-kwargs-python/):

```
def a(x):
    return 0.2 * x[1] - 0.4 * x[0]

def b(x):
    return 0.4 * x[0] - 0.2 * x[1]

def c(x):
    return 0.5 * x[0]

def d(x):
    return 0.5 * x[1]

def combine(*args):
    return lambda x: [f(x) for f in args]

abcd = combine(a, b, c, d)
print(abcd([1.3, 2.9]))
```

gives

```
[0.05999999999999994, -0.05999999999999994, 0.65, 1.45]
```